# AppleScriptで、リストから設定を選択させたい

Tags: macos, applescript

ボタンをクリックさせる方法はわかったのですが、メニューから項目を選択させる方法がわからず困っております。

環境設定のNetwork Link Conditionerを開き、設定をOnするスクリプトは、下記のように書き、動作しています。

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell window "Network Link Conditioner"
        click button "ON"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

[image: メニュー]

これにリストメニューから100%Lossを選ぶ動作を追加したく存じます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の箇所は、下記のように実現することができました。

```
   tell group 1
            click pop up button 1
            click menu item "Wifi" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
```

コード全体は以下のようになりました。

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell window "Network Link Conditioner"
            click button "ON"
            tell group 1
                click pop up button 1

                click menu item "Wifi" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```